# How can I use Chart.js to build Piecharts for Bonita Soft?

Tags: angularjs, charts, bonita

How can I use `Chart.js` to make charts (Pie charts, Bar charts etc) and use in Bonita BPM solution?

Comment: hello, Im looking for the same thing now. did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a widget in Ui-designer for your chart. in widget you can add char.js in asset and use it.